# How to get date in a Custom Object from a date field in Archer?

Tags: archer, rsa-archer-grc

I have tried getting the value with JavaScript functions but getting Invalid date.
Also,

**var dat = new Date(String(Archertech.UI.GenericContent.GetInstance().getFieldValue(ScheduledDate,false)));**

gives the date from one field only, but there are two date fields.

I wonder where can I get the list of functions like

**Archertech.UI.GenericContent.GetInstance().getFieldValue(ScheduledDate,false)**

Answer (score 1):

There is a Client Manager frontend API that is available which has many functions that will give you the values from fields in the Application.

To get all the function list :

1. Add a new Custom Object named "debugger" with the code  debugger;
2. Save that object > Open Application > Add a new / Open a record
3. Open Browser's Console i.e F12 > Developer Tools > Console
4. Set Target to frame : Record.aspx
5. type "$CM." will get you a list of supported functions

Now, to get a date field value, use `$CM.getFieldValue(fieldId);`

Answer (score 1):

Sourabh, you'd have to call the `CM.getFieldValue()` function for each date field you want to get the value of.  There is no such function to retrieve **all** date fields at once.

RSA Archer doesn't provide any documentation for client-side functions.